# Flutter_Switch state on PageView widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using the package Flutter_Switch to create a switch button on a PageView.

When i turn the switch 'ON' and move to the new page within my PageView the state of the switch on is already 'ON', like it's inherited the state from the previous page.

Is there a way to control this switch per PageView page?

Link to code snippet of my PageView widget
[Code Snip](https://snipsave.com/user/deanball/snippet/RRZQvbaegPJbgYKVmf/)

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet

Comment: Thanks, I've added the switch widget code within the PageView

Comment: can you include full minimal widget?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Added a link to my code. Thanks.